# AQMP ReceiverLink Loses Connection

Tags: c#, azure, amqp

We are using the AmqpNetLite library to connect to an Azure Queue.  We have this issue where, on occasion, the subscriber to the queue created using the `ReceiverLink` stops receiving messages.  It is suggested to subscribe to the AMQP object Close events and reestablish the connection.  The Close events however never appear to be raised.  The scenario to reproduce issue:

1. Create `ReceiverLink` and subscribe to the queue.
2. Pull the network cable to cause connection to drop.
3. After waiting after a few SEND (ch=0) Empty log entries plug the cable back in.  After this scenario, the receiver link message callback is never called again.  Also, a Close event is also never received.

Also tried setting the `IdleTimeOut`.  I do see a connection log log event but as explained above, the event handler is never invoked.